# this. java and objects

Tags: java, object, geometry, radius

I created two circle objects that (from what I thought) each hold a different value for radius. However, the output for each Circle object is the same. From my minute understanding of Programming, I was under the impression that if you don't pass a parameter for your object, the object uses the default constructor. Can someone please explain where I am wrong, and how I can go about receiving two different circle objects with different radius values?

```
//create circle object use method to find area

package circle;

public class Circle {

    static final double PI = 3.14;
    static private double radius;
    static private double area;
    static private String name;

    //default constructor 
    public Circle()
    {
      this.radius = 2;
    }

    //constructor with argument
    public Circle(int radius)
    {
        this.name = "JOESHMO-THE-CIRCLE";
        this.radius = radius;

    }

    public static double getRadius()
    {

        return radius;
    }

    public static double getArea()
    {

        //calculate area
        area = PI * Math.pow(radius,2);

        return area;
    }

    public static String getName()
    {

        return name;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Circle circle1 = new Circle(4);

        Circle circle2 = new Circle();

        double answer = circle1.getArea();

        System.out.println(answer);
        System.out.println("The radius of " + circle1.getName() + " is " + circle1.getRadius());

        System.out.println(circle2.getArea());

    }

}
```

the output is currently:

```
12.56

The radius of JOESHMO-THE-CIRCLE is 2.0

12.56
```

Comment: Get rid of those static fields and methods -- make them non-static!

Comment: static fields would hold the values, just remove static keyword

Comment: Your problem is that the static fields are shared by all instances of the class, and so if you change it in one instance, you change it in all, and that is specifically why these fields and methods above (except for the main method) should **not** be static.

Comment: Thank you for the fast replies!

Comment: Should search before you ask question